# Bootloop after modification of "/system/bin/playlpm" file

Tags: boot-loop, power-on, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

Modification of `playlpm` file sets my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini I9192 into boot-loop.
Instead of normal booting, it goes back to battery charging screen without animation, reboots again and keeps repeating this cycle. It happens only at the attempt to auto-start the phone by connecting a charger. Otherwise phone is fully operational.

Is there any option of "reboot" or similar command that forces S4 Mini to come out of the bootloop?

**Note:** `/system` is write-protected in Galaxy S4 Mini and needs to be remount to save something on it.  Used command: `mount -o remount,rw /system`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get it in recovery mode and re-flash it. [There's a tutorial here](http://www.samsungsfour.com/tutorials/how-to-resolve-android-boot-loop.html) if you need it.
If that doesn't help, I'm afraid the only option will be to carry it to service for repair.