# Modification of `playlpm` file causes shutdown instead of rebooting

Tags: auto-start

Modification of `playlpm` file causes shutdown instead of rebooting my Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini I9192.

Updated  playlpm reboots the phone after typing the terminal command "playlpm" when Android OS is completely loaded.

But the same  playlpm file behaves strange when S4 Mini is off. S4 Mini shows the battery icon without animation when it realizes that a charger is connected. After that it gives control to playlpm as expected, but in this case playlpm shuts the phone down. Seconds later the phone realizes that it's powered up, shows the static battery icon and the cycle repeats. The cycle ends if I disconnect the charger. The phone goes off.

Is there any option of "reboot" or "shutdown" command that forces sleeping S4 Mini to load Android when powered up, not to shutdown?

**Note:** `/system` is write-protected in Galaxy S4 Mini and needs to be remount to save something on it.  Used command: `mount -o remount,rw /system`

Comment: Duplicate: [Bootloop after modification of "/system/bin/playlpm" file](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131696/bootloop-after-modification-of-system-bin-playlpm-file)